# Use Custom Annotation Image in MapBox SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I've recently followed the tutorial for integrating MapBox into my SwiftUI app using [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/ios-swiftui/) by MapBox.  I'm now looking to customize the image used for the annotation marker on the map.  Has anybody done this or is willing to give a short example of how this can be accomplished with MapBox and SwiftUI?  My current code looks nearly identical to the tutorial above.

Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out, so I'll post this for other users.

The current annotation guide doesn't offer any example on how to do this directly in SwiftUI, however, you can use some of the functions built-in to accomplish the exact task.  In the `Coordinator` class shown in the original documentation, you can simply add the following method to show whichever image you'd like at each annotation.

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
            
    return MGLAnnotationImage(image: UIImage(named: "imageName")!, reuseIdentifier: "map-marker")
            
}
```